# Getting a countdown from string 02:00 minutes Android

Tags: android, datetime, time, format

I have a textView that has the value 2:00 that is representing 2 minutes and 00 seconds to go.

I have a stopwatch function that will count up. I have integrated them to work upwars.

What I'm trying to do is to for every seconds that pass I will show

```
1:59
1:58 
1:57
```

and so on until reaching 0:00.

The help I need is to reformat the textview text to time and than for every go seconds - 1

In C# I would probably use 2:00.addseconds(-1) 2:00 is representing the reformatted textview.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use an instruction like this to get the start time:

```
long start=System.currentTimeMillis();
```

then you can create another variable which you will check into a while loop, for example:

```
long now=System.currentTimeMillis();

while((now-start)<120000){

  now=System.currentTimeMillis();
  if((now-start)%1000==0){
     //update textview
  }}
```

this should work, let me know if you have problems

Comment: Isn't this going to peg the cpu while it sits in the `while` loop?

Comment: well, I have not considered this factor.. I don't know maybe if your application always uses the countdown that might be a problem, but if it is a feature you don't use often you could implement this counter the way I told you

Comment: or maybe you could start another thread or a service which contains the loop, so you can do other things while it changes the text view

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of time as an int somewhere.

```
int mSeconds = 120; // 120 seconds is 2 minutes
```

At your scheduler/timer

```
mSeconds -= 1; // run every second
```

Then in your text-writing loop

```
String minutes = Integer.toString(mSeconds / 60);
String seconds = Integer.toString(mSeconds % 60);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanx 
The Int mSecond code did the code real good

the problem i now get is that the 
countdown is 13 sec of. If i start at 0:00 and count that one up i get on the downcounter 
2:13 at 2:00 
you can say that they are not in sync :(

I need to set the Refresh rate att 1000 millisec
I think it is because it miss a second every once in a while 
because of the high refreshrate.

Orginal was set to a refresh rate at 100 millisec.
i´ve tryied a couple of settings but non work

i´m Using StopWatch class to count the timeelapsed.